# Allowing apps to access specified contacts

Tags: ios, contacts, privacy

iOS has a feature of allowing only photos you select to be accessible from an app instead of allowing all photos.

Is there a similar feature where I can specify which contacts should be available to an app instead of sharing all of my contact list?

Comment: I have been wanting this for a very long time.
I put a [feedback into Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) for this a while back. And will keep doing so I would suggest every one does this. It has always seemed made to me that this feature is omitted.

Comment: In your [App Privacy Report](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/control-access-to-information-in-apps-iph251e92810/17.0/ios/17.0)- do you see one app in particular that access contacts in a manner you don't agree with? I agree with the comment that we should request this from Apple or they do a better job letting us know which contact an app touches...

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 17 this isn't a feature. What is new is the App Privacy Report and we all might agitate via [feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) and post purchase surveys to get Apple to improve that to enumerate how many contacts are accessed so at least people know what the implication of sharing the data was after the fact.